# what's the point of using subsonic's active record?

Tags: subsonic

When using linq to sql are there any benefits of using subsonic's active record as they are similar (table=class). Is this supported for Oracle or DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple comparisons/discussions:

- http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Comparisons
- [Subsonic 3 LINQ vs LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295341/subsonic-3-linq-vs-linq-to-sql)
- [Linq to Sql vs Nhibernate vs SubSonic vs Stored Procedure (Help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125956/linq-to-sql-vs-nhibernate-vs-subsonic-vs-stored-procedure-help)

For your other question about database support, see:

- http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases

Oracle support for SubSonic 3 is slated for SubSonic 3.1, which is currently a couple months away.  See the discussion in the SubSonic Google groups for the latest development news:

- http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/topics?start=